# Getting Error Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dbcontext, ef-database-first, ef-core-3.1

I have a .NET CORE console app which I already created a database for and want to scaffold the model and db context using the Database First Approach , I have a database populated with countries that I want to create a country model for and manipulate in my project.

> Important note that I only have one project in this solution

When I type this in my package manager console

> `Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=DESKTOP-BJPQ694\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
>   Catalog=CountryOrigin;User ID=quinoa;Password=chelseatext;ConnectTimeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

I get the error :

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

Comment: Could you share your package reference in your .csproj file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you might be using older version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`? Try updating it to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1`.

Reason for your error could be `DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute` was only supported till `Entity Framework Core 1.1` which was under `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure`.

As you are using newer versions `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure` does not include `DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute` & throws the error. Verify same on MSDN here

- [DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute efcore-1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure?view=efcore-1.1)
- [DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute efcore-3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure?view=efcore-3.1).